# How to execute code from wo differnt azure repositories?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am a newbie to Azure DevOps and want to execute code from two different repositories and perform a different operation on each repo for e.g:

```
Stages:
  - stage: Data_Setup
    jobs:
      - job: Data_Setup  // Want to perform this operation on repo1
        timeoutInMinutes: 120
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
        continueOnError: true
        steps:
          - task: Gradle@2
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              tasks: cleanReports test aggregate
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  - stage: Run_all_regression_tests     // Want to perform this operation on repo2
    jobs:
      - job: Run_all_regression_tests     
        timeoutInMinutes: 100
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
        continueOnError: true
        steps:
          - task: Gradle@2
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              tasks: cleanReports createJar test aggregate
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Comment: read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource

Answer (score 0):

You add multiple repositories by ,

```
  resources:
repositories:
```

and when you want to use a specific repository you can checkout that in the step using "checkout" like below (Copied from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops))

```html
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyBitbucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitbucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitbucketOrgOrUser/MyBitbucketRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository # In a different organization
    endpoint: MyAzureReposGitServiceConnection
    type: git
    name: OtherProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
- checkout: MyBitbucketRepo
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Comment: I am able to do checkout but as I mentioned in my how I can perform operations on my specific repo?